# Contagem incorreta de campos $_FILE

Tags: php

Na seguinte estrutura:

```
<input type="file" id="imagem_01" name="imagem[]" />
<input type="file" id="imagem_02" name="imagem[]" />
<input type="file" id="imagem_03" name="imagem[]" />
```

Ao enviar eu uso dessa forma:

`echo count($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'])`;

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1491629_701232416581971_1576042449_n.jpg
            [1] => 1798325_1420590811513009_1411268959_n.jpg
            [2] => 
        )
)
```

Me retornando 03 campos, porém, se eu selecionar dois campos ainda assim aparecem contagem 03.

Minha questão é: Como eu faço para que retorne o número correto de campos preenchidos do tipo imagem?

Comment: O form envia o campo, porém vazio. Teria que fazer a contagem dos que estão setados

Comment: `count(array_filter($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']))` provavelmente já emilinará todos os valores nulos.

Comment: Perfeito @AndersonCarlosWoss, era exatamente isso que eu precisava. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você cria o campo no HTML, um valor nulo será enviado ao PHP, justamente porque o campo existe e, as vezes, é necessário que seja preenchido, deixando para que o desenvolvedor faca a validacão. Se no seu caso o campo pode estar em branco, basta você utilizar a funcão `array_filter` para eliminar valores nulos:

```
$tmpnames = array_filter($_FILES["imagem"]['tmp_name']);
echo count($tmpnames); // 2
```

Isso porque, quando não passado o segundo parâmetro da funcão, o PHP removerá do array todos os valores que são analisados como falso. Sendo um array de strings, serão removidos todos os valores nulos ou string vazia.